# Elasticsearch filter/aggregation by next/previous array item

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, aggregation-framework, bucket

Let say three are these three documents and need to write an **elasticsearch** query which gets an item name parameter and returns next items(calculate by using order) of it with the occurrence.

itemArray is defined as nestedObject, but not necessary to be nested. I'm lost in the documentation a bit. Any help will be appreciated.

**Data Example:**

**doc-1**

```
{
  "id" : 0
  "itemArray": [
     {
        "name":"X",
        "order" : 0
     },
     {
        "name":"Y",
        "order" : 1
     },
     {
        "name":"Z",
        "order" : 2
     }
  ]
}
```

**doc-2**

```
{
  "id" : 1
  "itemArray": [
     {
        "name":"X",
        "order" : 0
     },
     {
        "name":"Y",
        "order" : 1
     },
     {
        "name":"T",
        "order" : 2
     }
  ]
}
```

**doc-3**

```
{
  "id" : 2
  "itemArray": [
     {
        "name":"X",
        "order" : 0
     },
     {
        "name":"Y",
        "order" : 1
     },
     {
        "name":"Z",
        "order" : 2
     }
  ]
}
```

**Response Example** for the input "**X**", There are **three document contain Y**; after **X** in its array according to order:

```
{
    "Y": 3
}
```

**Response Example** for the input "**Y**" There are **two document contain Z** and **one document contain T**; after **Y** in its array according to order:

```
{
    "Z": 2,
    "T": 1
}
```

ElasticSearch version: **6.2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty feasible if you consider [denormalizing your data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html) a little bit.

### How can "next element in array" aggregation be implemented?

Consider that your mapping would look like this:

```
PUT nextval
{
  "mappings": {
    "item": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "itemArray": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "nextName": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here we store in a `nested` next value of the array explicitly. Now let's insert the data:

```
POST nextval/item/0
{
  "id" : 0,
  "itemArray": [
     {
        "name":"X",
        "nextName":"Y"
     },
     {
        "name":"Y",
        "nextName":"Z"
     },
     {
        "name":"Z"
     }
  ]
}

POST nextval/item/1
{
  "id" : 1,
  "itemArray": [
     {
        "name":"X",
        "nextName":"Y"
     },
     {
        "name":"Y",
        "nextName":"T"
     },
     {
        "name":"T"
     }
  ]
}

POST nextval/item/2
{
  "id" : 2,
  "itemArray": [
     {
        "name":"X",
        "nextName":"Y"
     },
     {
        "name":"Y",
        "nextName":"Z"
     },
     {
        "name":"Z"
     }
  ]
}
```

And use a query like this to obtain the result for the input `X`:

```
POST nextval/item/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "itemArray",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "itemArray.name": "X"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "1. setup nested": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "itemArray"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "2. filter agg results": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "itemArray.name": "X"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "3. aggregate by nextName": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "itemArray.nextName"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output will look like this:

```
{
  ...,
  "aggregations": {
    "1. setup nested": {
      "doc_count": 9,
      "2. filter agg results": {
        "doc_count": 3,
        "3. aggregate by nextName": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "Y",
              "doc_count": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If we do the query for the input `Y` the output will be:

```
{
  ...,
  "aggregations": {
    "1. setup nested": {
      "doc_count": 9,
      "2. filter agg results": {
        "doc_count": 3,
        "3. aggregate by nextName": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "Z",
              "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
              "key": "T",
              "doc_count": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### How does it work?

One important thing to know about nested objects is:

> each nested object is indexed as a hidden separate document

I recommend reading [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) of the Guide, they provide great explanation and examples.

Since these objects are separate, we lose the information about their position in the array. This is the reason you put `order` there in the first place.

That's why we put the `nextName` field in the nested object: so the object itself knows which is its neighbor.

### Ok, but why the aggregation is so complex?

Let's recap. In our query there are basically 4 essential points:

1. query by the `itemArray.name==X`
2. 1-level aggregation, [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html)
3. 2-level aggregation, [`filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html)
4. 3-level aggregation, [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

The 1) is pretty obvious: we only want documents that correspond our request. The 2) is also straightforward: since `itemArray` is a `nested`, we can only do aggregations within `nested` context.

The 3) one is tricky. Let's return to the output of the query:

```
{
  ...,
  "aggregations": {
    "1. setup nested": {
      "doc_count": 9,
      "2. filter agg results": {
        "doc_count": 3,
        "3. aggregate by nextName": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "Z",
              "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
              "key": "T",
              "doc_count": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `doc_count` of the first aggregation is 9. Why 9? Because this is the amount of nested objects we have in the documents matched our search query.

This is why we need the 3) aggregation: from all items select only those that have `itemArray.name==X`.

And the 4) one is again simple: just count how many times each term of field `itemArray.nextName` is met.

### Are there better ways?

Probably, yes. It depends on your data and on your needs and how free are you to change the mapping. For instance, if you are just exploring your data, the potential of [scripted aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) is huge.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply Nikolay. what if there is a condition on this like previous items must be "X" and "Y" consecutive. consider same data on the question. response must be "T:1 Z:2" 
Can we have this type of query?

I tried to write a filter script but could not get success result. actually could not reach array items on filter script before the aggregation.

Comment: @GkhnSr I think in the case when you need two previous and aggregate on the third you'd need to add them in `itemArray` like this: `{"prevName": "X", "name": "Y", "nextName": "Z"}`, and update the query and the filter with new condition (`prevName=X && name=Y`).

Comment: actually I mean that there might be more than one consecutive previous inputs for the filter. With your suggestion I need to set all the previousNames to for each like (prevName=X,Y). There must be better approach to find the items which has same previous path.
example data:`"X>Y>Z", "X>Y>Z", "X>Y>T"`
filter by previous: `"X>Y"`
expected result: `"Z:2, T:1"`

Comment: @GkhnSr you may concatenate these ids and do a query for the entire prefix, until the beginning: `[{"name": "X"}, {"prefix": "X", "name" "Y"}, {"prefix": "X.Y", "name": "Z"}]` and the query part: `prefix="X.Y"`. The idea stays the same - put everything you need to query in a single item.

Comment: @GkhnSr If you manage to convert your list of ids into a string you may benefit from a [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-prefix-query.html). Like `"prefix": {"userActions": "login.selectItem.putInCart.checkOut"}`.

Comment: anyway, your answer is valid for this question and I'll accept it. But these approach looks like a bit tricky, I do not want to store all steps on each items. I'll need to write a script for these consecutive items to resolve my problem. Just a question; I can reach array items on terms aggregation script but cannot reach them on filter aggregation. Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: @GkhnSr if you are talking about `filter` in `nested` context (like in the answer`) then it should not be visible, since `nested` items only know about themselves, not their "parent" (enclosing document). About accepting the answer: unfortunately Elasticsearch is not a right tool for this, my work-around demonstrates feasibility but surely it's not "the killer feature" of Elasticsearch. If you find better solution it would be cool to see it here as well.